# How to test new user login?

Tags: linux, rhel, login, useradd

I've done some searching on Google and SE and have not found what I need using my search terms.

Accessing RHEL 5.10 (Tikanga) from Windows 7.

I am making a new user and need to make sure their login works, with these restrictions:

- No other services are set up so I can't telnet from my PC to the machine.
- While I currently have a shell window open to linux via Exceed, I can't use another  Exceed startup profile (.xs file) to log in. I need to make sure the linux login works before I set it up in Exceed.
- I'm trying not to use any client program like Putty.
- Exceed is having problems so I'm trying to take that out of the loop to figure out what is going wrong.

So how do I test their login from my linux command window?

- When I do `/bin/login` I keep getting a message about an incorrect password, but I know the password is right. I just created it. And sometimes the shell window just closes.

Thank you.

Comment: `su -l <username>` maybe?